# Ubuntu screen struck at purple screen

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, nomodeset

I am running two OSs in my system. I have booted into Ubuntu after a long time. I had updated to be installed, it asked me to enter a password which will be used after boot. It said waiting to be installed and the progress was showing waiting so I canceled it. Then when I restarted the system and tried to boot into Ubuntu, it is stuck here and I also tried different methods by pressing on Ubuntu and changing `quiet splash` to `no splash` and also `quiet splash` to `nomodeset`. I also tried to enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd>. Nothing is working. What should I do? Should I reinstall the OS?

Comment: I don't know much of Ubuntu nor I use as main os....When I was in Ubuntu yesterday I saw a lot updates were ready to be downloaded and installed I clicked on os updates in package managaer.It asked for me to set a password.Then it was not responding and settings was also not responding.So I tried to restart and in the grub I selected Ubuntu then it struck at purple screen and also went into advanced Ubuntu settings and went to Ubuntu recovery it said there it said end kernel panic unable to mount and when I clicked on the upstart also it struck at loading Ubuntu generic

Comment: Your OS is bricked.. you shouldn't have cancelled. Now reinstall Ubuntu

Comment: Isn't there any other way

Comment: you can try `ctrl+alt+t` login in command line.
`sudo apt-get install -f`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get upgrade`
`sudo apt-apt autoclean`
if it doesn't solve the problem you have to reinstall boss..

Comment: When should I press ctrl+alt+t..when I press Ubuntu on grub or what

Comment: On grub choose ubuntu.. when you're stuck press ctrl+alt+t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by this:

1. Go to advance options for ubuntu in grub.
2. Go to ubuntu recovery mode which is written in brackets and do not chose the recovery which is present at top.Believe me if you have exact problem as me following other answers by going to recovery at 2 or 3 place in list does not help.Instead go to a recovery relatively bottom of list and chose it and that's it no more commands to deal with.The system itself deletes the corrupted updates.
3. Enter your username and password.

If some one else is facing same problem please do comment I will be happy to help Thank you.